# Conditional sum of table cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I had originally posted this question without posting the full algorithm. Here is the whole thing.

I have an HTML page like this:

```
<table id="inputTable"> 
    <tr>
       <td>Label1</td>
       <td><input type="text" value="" id="inputA1"></td>
       <td><span id="inputA1ErrMsg"/></span></td>
       <td><input type="text" value="" id="inputA1_"></td>
       <td><span id="inputA1ErrMsg_"/></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Label1</td>
       <td><input type="text" value="" id="inputA2"></td>
       <td><span id="inputA2ErrMsg"/></span></td>
       <td><input type="text" value="" id="inputA2_"></td>
       <td><span id="inputA2ErrMsg_"/></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Label1</td>
       <td><input type="text" value="" id="inputA3"></td>
       <td><span id="inputA3ErrMsg"/></span></td>
       <td><input type="text" value="" id="inputA3_"></td>
       <td><span id="inputA3ErrMsg_"/></span></td>
    </tr>
    // ... repeat all the way up to A15.
    <tr>
       <td>Label1</td>
       <td><input type="text" value="" id="inputB1"></td>
       <td><span id="inputB1ErrMsg"/></span></td>
       <td><input type="text" value="" id="inputB1_"></td>
       <td><span id="inputB1ErrMsg_"/></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Label1</td>
       <td><input type="text" value="" id="inputB2"></td>
       <td><span id="inputB2ErrMsg"/></span></td>
       <td><input type="text" value="" id="inputB2_"></td>
       <td><span id="inputB2ErrMsg"/></span></td>
    </tr>
    // ... so on up to E1. 
</table>
```

I want my JavaScript to do three things:

- It takes input `input*5` and sums up it up. If it is less than 20, show the next input.

  - `inputA5 + inputB5 < 20` than show input for `inputC*`

    In the same way, do it for `input*5_`. If it is less than 5, show the next set of input.
  - `inputA5_ + inputB5_ < 20` then show input for `inputC*_` which is `inputC1_`, `inputC2_`, `inputC3_`... else we hide it.
- Now if, let's say, they enter 20 for `inputA5` and 20 for `inputA5_`, then it would not only hide the input but the entire row.

To make it easier I added `class = "inputTrigger"` to each of `input*5` and `inputTrigger_` to each of `input*5_`.

**jQuery**

```
$("inputTable").on("change", "inputTrigger", function() { 
     inputChange(this.id, indexArray.indexOf(this.id.replace("input", "").replace("5", "")); // so we can get if it is A, B, C, D
});
```

**My functions:**

```
var indexArray = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};
function getTotal(id, index) { 
   var total = 0;
   var len = indexArray.length;
   for (var i = 0; i != len;  ++i) {
        total += parseFloat($(input + indexArray[i] + "5").val());
   }
   return total;
}

function inputChange(id,currentIndex) {
        var nextIndex, total, isShow, MAX_INDEX;
        nextIndex = +currentIndex + 1;
        MAX_INDEX= '5';
        if (nextIndex < MAX_INDEX) {
            total = parseFloat(getTotal(id, currentIndex));
            if (nextIndex === 1) {
                nextIndex += 1;
            }
            isShow = (total < 20.0 &&  document.getElementById(id).value > 0.0);
            showOrHideInput(isShow, nextIndex, resetValue);
            inputChange(id, nextIndex);
        }
    }

    function    showOrHideInput(isShow, nextIndex) {
             var id1 = $("#input" + nextIndex + "1");
             var id2 = $("#input" + nextIndex + "2");
             var id10 = .....
             var id1Other = $("#input" + nextIndex + "1_");
             var id2Other = $("#input" + nextIndex + "2_");
             var id10Other = ....
             if (isShow) { 
                 if (id1.length) {
                    id1.show();
                 }
                 // ... so on up to id10
             }
             else {
                 if (id1.length) {
                    id1.hide();
                 }
                 // .. so on up to id10
             }
             showOrHideRows(isShow, id1, id1Other);
             showOrHideRows(isShow, id2, id2Other);
             showOrHideRows(isShow, id3, id3Other);
             // ... up to id10.
   }

   function showOrHideRows(isShow, id, idOther) {
         if (isShow) {
             id.closest("tr").show();
         } else {
            if (!idOther.is(":visible")) {
               id.closest("tr").hide();
            }
         }
   }
```

I know my function works but it seems really slow on IE 8 and 9, and sometimes causes a memory leak. I have analyzed the speed with `dynaTrace` and `showOrHideInput` takes over 800 ms.

1. What is the fastest way to tell if a jQuery element is visible? It seems `is(":visible")` has performance hit.
2. What is the best way to hide the first ancestor table row (in terms of performance)?

Comment: Often a good way to speed up jQuery code is to use less jQuery. This means being comfortable with the native API, and using it directly. For example, if you know *how* the element is being hidden, then you don't need `.is(':visible')`.

Answer (score 1):

As a general advice - use less document-wide selectors. I meant that you always selected something from entire document context:

```
$(input + indexArray[i] + "5")
//.........
$("#input" + nextIndex + "1")
```

Try to narrow context - for example, assign a class to all '#inputWhatever and then

```
var myInputs = $(".assignedClass");
$("#input" + nextIndex + "1", myInputs);
```

The code in

```
if (id1.length) {
  id1.show();
}
```

looks strange: if element length is 0, it is hidden anyway, isn't it? I'm not sure in this for all kinds of browsers... If what I suppose is true, better do:

```
if(isShow) {
  $(".assignedClass").show();
} else {
  $(".assignedClass").hide();
}
```

Other things:

```
if (!idOther.is(":visible"))
```

looks better in style as

```
if (idOther.is(":hidden"))
```

Btw, what if `isShow` is `false` and `!idOther.is(":visible"` is `false` too? What about `id` visibility? May it be a bug?

If you use a lot of "if something then show else hide" consider `toggle()`

Comment: id1.length is to check if element exists or not. If it exists than id1.show() will show the element.

2.) showOrHideRows deals with isShow = false.. if both are false, hide the entire row. (not just the inputs/table cell).